# Don't want to clear textbox values after button click in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

My values are getting cleared when I hit the search button, I don't want my values to be clear after search.

My view markup is as follows:

```
<form class="d-flex" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Employee">
    <input name="name" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Name" aria-label="Search" />
    <input name="email" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Search" />
    <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

And this is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name, string email)
{
    var emp = _employeeRepository.GetEmployees();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        emp = emp.Where(x => x.FName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) || x.LName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())).ToList();
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        emp = emp.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(email)).ToList();
    }

    return View(emp);
}
```

Please help, how can I preserve my textbox values.

Thanks

Comment: use asp-for... ex:  <input asp-for="name" class="form-control"... make sure your returned data includes name and email.  (Create a class object that contains employees and search values)  The search values, name and email will be posted...  bind them  (use [BindProperty]) and add to the class object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0